# Mac os 10.11.3 shortcuts

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a Macbook that failed and I had to reinstall OS and updated it as well. Now it has some very annoying behavior like  ] opens Frontrow(?) and command + [ opens Voiceover. Also selecting 'Use all F keys as standard function keys' turns F key behavior completely erratic like F3 types § as well as has some special meaning depending on application Im using.

Is there a way to map keys to functions? Or at least make input only affect the focused application?

Comment: You've got something else very wrong going on with your system. Troubleshoot that first. Front Row hasn't been in the OS for half a decade now (10.6 Snow Leopard was the last release to have it), and hitting "]" was never the way to invoke it. WTF is going on with your system?

Comment: Well, it had a hardware failure and logic board was replaced. For now I just need to make it work for the next little bit while I wait for a new one to be delivered. Its a company laptop.

Comment: Is it an ancient machine that came with Snow Leopard, and that's what you restored? Is the keyboard properly connected to the MLB? Is the right keyboard layout selected?

Comment: Yes, its an ancient machine. Says its from mid 2012. Messing around with input sources actually did solve some problems. Now maybe if Google tells me how make a custom one....

Comment: If it's from 2012, then the earliest OS it could boot was from after Front Row was removed. How did you get Front Row onto that system? Did you restore from a lived-in backup, or via an Apple-provided clean OS restore/install method? Or are you not actually seeing Front Row? Your problem description leaves a lot of questions.

Comment: Not sure. Its a black screen with some apps floating around. Kinda looks like the screen shot in Wikipedia. Might be something else. This also happens to be my first Mac. Thats why I marked it with a (?) in the first place :)